# infinite scroll - mysql limit not working

Tags: php, mysql

I'm building an infinite scroll for a photo gallery of a website.
It starts with 6 photos loaded and should load 3 more photos every-time the user reach the end of the page.

So, me first mysql is:

```
SELECT * FROM tb_galeriaarte ORDER BY datafoto DESC LIMIT 0,6
```

When the user reach the end of the page, I'm using the following mysql command to add 3 more photos:

```
SELECT * FROM tb_galeriaarte ORDER BY datafoto DESC LIMIT 6,9
```

The problem is that it returns 4 records instead of 3 and I have no idea why it happens!
Somebody can help me with that? what am I doing wrong?!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To add three more photos, the second `limit` would be:

```
limit 6, 3
```

The arguments are offset and number of records.  You are asking for 9 records starting on the 7th (the offset starts counting from zero).

Answer (score 2):

You should learn more about MySQL.

```
LIMIT [start, ] count
```

So, in your second case it will be

```
LIMIT 6, 3
```

Here you can learn more about LIMIT: [doc](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-limit.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Just write

```
SELECT * FROM tb_galeriaarte ORDER BY datafoto DESC LIMIT 6,3
```

2nd digit of LIMIT points quantity but not top limit